# Some images are rotating 90 degrees counter clockwise

Tags: javascript, image, image-rotation

I am allowing user to upload a pic for their item.  When I test it, some of my pics on my desktop look normal, but when I upload, the rotate 90 degrees counter clockwise.  I believe this has to do with how I held my iPhone.  Is there an easy way to fix this.  I have the following javascript function that builds my cards.  I can upload an image per card.  How can I set rotation so it won't be counter clockwise>

```
        $(document)
        .ready(function() {

            $.each(itemNumbers, 
                function(i, value) {
                    $('.main_card_shell').append(
                    "<div class='card_content card_style' id='card0'>" +

                           "<div class='subcard_style box_title'>" + 
                               '<img class="card_image" src="' + imgpath[i] + '" alt="Item #1" />' +     
                               '<div class="profile">' +
```

is there a line I can add under my `<img class="card_image" src="' + imgpath[i] + '" alt="Item #1" />` to handle rotation?

Comment: What relevance does the code you posted have to your question?

Comment: I was trying to show where I was loading my img from my database.   imgpath[I] is where I am loading my pic.  Didn't know if there was a ling before or after that that I could add to handle rotation.  Or maybe I need to hand it on php side before I save to database or right when user select image.

Answer (score 0):

The JPEG image contains metadata specifying the JPEG rotation (see [this post](https://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/exif-orientation.html)), but that solely depends on whether image viewer is capable of handling that according.  Most of the modern desktop viewers should but browser may not have such capacity.

One way you can get around that would be having a backend to extract the data and even rotate the image for you.

Comment: Lin, are you saying in my php file where I push my image to my database, I need to handle it there?  Do you have a good example of a php function that could handle this?

Comment: He is saying windows is messing with you, the images are already rotated on your hard disk

Comment: @BEP, I am not familiar with PHP, but you can check out PHP Image rotation and Exif reader via http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php